# how maintain the format in outlook in vba

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

this a part of my code to send an e-mail by outlook in vba. However, I am want to send with the first sentence in bold. Ex: where I write the text in first body (how I named the cell of each paragraph), I can choose where I want the text be bold, but these format do not remain when the vba create the e-mail

Any idea?

EX: **My name is Vinicius**. I am from **Brazil** and like **Soccer**

[image]

```
    pretit = Sheets(CurrSh).Range("pretit").Value
    midtit = Sheets(CurrSh).Range("midtit").Value
    prebod = Sheets(CurrSh).Range("prebod").Value
    bod = Sheets(CurrSh).Range("bod").Value
    postbod = Sheets(CurrSh).Range("postbod").Value
    body2 = Sheets(CurrSh).Range("body2").Value
    body3 = Sheets(CurrSh).Range("body3").Value
    body4 = Sheets(CurrSh).Range("body4").Value
    report = Sheets(CurrSh).Range("report").Value 

 If Sheets(CurrSh).Range("body4").Value <> vbEmpty Then

                            'Set ObjApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
                            While (Sheets(CurrSh).Range("emailad_ini").Offset(n, 0).Value <> "")
                            emailad = Sheets(CurrSh).Range("emailad_ini").Offset(n, 0).Value
                            firstname = Sheets(CurrSh).Range("firstname_ini").Offset(n, 0).Value


                            Set objMail(n) = ObjApp.CreateItem(0)

                            objMail(n).display
                            objMail(n).To = emailad
                            objMail(n).Subject = pretit & " " & firstname & midtit
                            objMail(n).HtmlBody = "<HTML><BODY><FONT FACE='Arial'><FONT SIZE='2'>" & prebod & " " & firstname & "," & "<br>" & "<br>" & bod & "<br>" & "<br>" & body2 & "<br>" & "<br>" & body3 & "<br>" & "<br>" & body4 & "<br>" & "<br>" & postbod & objMail(n).HtmlBody & "</FONT></FONT></BODY></HTML>"
                            objMail(n).Attachments.Add (report)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using `.HTMLBody` you would just enclose everything you want bold in an HTML bold tag like this:

```
Not Bold <b>This is bold</b> This is no longer bold.
```

Comment: I tried this, but I want some more flexible. I mean, i want to write the text, which changes every day, and the vba maintain the same format from excel cell. As i showed above, some parts/words would be in bold and others not.

Comment: That's what this will allow you to do.

Comment: You mean you want the formatting you did in Excel to apply to the email? To do that, you would need to use this: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm

Comment: I want a code that copy and paste special in the same format that i wrote in excel cell. automatically way.

Comment: I added a picture above at my ask what i am saying

Comment: I suppose you can try getting the data from the clipboard, but i'm not sure that will work: here's an explanation : http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?11665-VBA-paste-from-clipboard-to-email